# SQL query execution speed

Tags: sql, execution

Is it better, in terms of execution speed in sql, to have 2 different tables with the names 'image' and 'video' or 1 table with the name 'media' and a column with the name 'type'.

Will the execution speed be the same for this 2 querys?

'SELECT * FROM image WHERE id=x';

'SELECT * FROM media WHERE id=x AND type="image"'

Comment: what do your tests show far? Do you need help interpreting the execution plans? (p.s: The type thing does not change anything, as you are already using a primary key to query for data. It will just result in an additional comparision that can be considered obsolete since you know the id.).

Comment: I have the same columns for that two tables and there will be more tables added later with the same structure. I thought combining them into one table is a good idea, but if i'll have to much data in them, i guess it will have a bad effect on the performance.

Comment: I don't understand the brain which downvotes a good question. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes little difference.  For performance, your tables should have an index (the first would be `image(id)`; the second would be `media(id, type)`).

There is a slight inefficiency for the `media` table, because the records are larger: the type information is stored on each row.  This results in the corresponding tables have a few more data pages, an effect that would only be important when you start having millions of records.

Balancing this are the (potential) advantages of storing content in a single table.  If you have foreign key relationships that can be either images or video, then a single `MediaId` can be be used for that relationship.  If you have queries that are combining the two (how many "media" does a user have?), then having them in the same table is an advantage.  If they have other common attributes (such as creation time, byte size, format, and so on), then having them in one table provides a single point of reference.

In other words, the performance difference is negligible.  The data model should be based on the entity descriptions for your application.

Answer (score 0):

As @GordonLinoff already said, you should better take care for you data model; and also be sure to have indexes.

Only if you have **millions** of records, then such optimization considerations should come into place.

Just as an additional note: If you have two separate tables, then you could theoretically put them into two separate tablespaces on separate disks. Thus, the server could fetch data from the two tables in parallel, and this would gain speed.